# brew services says postgresql is started but there are no postgresql processes running

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

What does `brew services` say is happening for postgresql ?

```
$ brew services  | grep post
postgresql    started steve /Users/steve/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

But no processes are running:

```
$ps -ef | grep post | grep -v grep

(empty)

$ps -ef | grep pg | grep -v pg
 (empty)
```

So what does `started` then mean?

Comment: Have you figured this out?